# Open Modal Component in React

Tags: reactjs

I've got a modal component, that I would like to show when a button is clicked in the parent component, but still have it closed using the default onClose event.  The modal:

```
function AddJobModal(props: AppProps) {
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const handleClose = () => setOpenModal(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpenModal(props.open);
    }, [props.open])

    return (
        <Modal
            open={openModal}
            onClose={handleClose}
        ></Modal>
    );
}
```

In my parent component I call it:

```
function Main() {
    const [openAddJobModal, setOpenAddJobModal] = useState(false);

    const showAddJobForm = () => {
        setOpenAddJobModal(true);
    };

    return (
           <div>
                <AddJobModal open={openAddJobModal}></AddJobModal>
                <Button onClick={showAddJobForm}>
                    Add Job
                </Button>
            </div>
     );
}
```

This works only once.  After closing the modal, it no longer opens by clicking the button.  What would be the proper way of wiring this up?

Comment: You only need state in the parent component.  Just pass the modal state and the setter to close it to AddJobModal and you're done.

Comment: Thanks @jmargolisvt, that worked. Want to put your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it?